# Shortcut to change Type of Sequencer View

Tags: video-sequence-editor, shortcut

There's three buttons in the VSE header that let you turn on/off the preview and sequencer:

[image]

Do these have a keyboard shortcut?  And if no, is it possible to set one up?

Comment: It's possible, but you'll have to write your own operator. ([Related](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1646/599)). I've written most of one, but I can't seem to figure out how to add arguments to a custom operator..? I may have to ask that as a question ;)

Comment: @gandalf3 give the operator a property, then specify the property value when putting the operator in a layout, or when adding to shortcuts the property will be visible to set.

Comment: @sambler Thanks! I think added a property (I might have done something wrong), but was trying to call it like an argument.. It seems my operator isn't needed anymore anyway..

Comment: @gandalf3, if it's already done, you could still post it, especially since there's an [unresolved bug](https://developer.blender.org/T35709) which causes problems when you go into Preview mode (instead of skipping straight to Both mode).

Comment: @Garrett It's partially working, however there is some strangeness with global shortcuts only working when in sequencer only view (despite being assigned in sequencer "global").. I also failed to get an Enum property working, so I'm using a String as a workaround..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default shortcut to change view type in the sequencer is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>

The one shortcut cycles through each display option.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Sambler, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> already cycles through the three sequencer views.

It's also possible to set up a shortcut to toggle between two of them:

- Go to `File` > `User Settings` > `Input`, and expand `Sequencer`, then expand `Sequencer (Global)`
- Scroll down, hit `Add New` and expand the new shortcut
- In the textbox that has "none" in it, type `wm.context_toggle_enum`
- Set the keyboard shortcut to what you want
- In the Context Attributions box, type `space_data.view_type`
- In the two Value boxes, type `SEQUENCER` and `SEQUENCER_PREVIEW`

[image]

You could have figured out the last two steps by changing the sequencer view and looking at the output in the Info window.

Comment: This is the solution I'll be using until the developers fix [this bug](https://developer.blender.org/T35709) which causes problems after opening the PREVIEW view.